# Mongodb Nodejs manage next day record with previous day record conditionaly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, koa

I am very new in mongodb and nodejs. I am currently working with attendance system. I need to marge  next dated first record with current dated record where the current date shift is night shift.
My current record looks like bellow.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2023-04-01",
        "shift": {
            "date": "2023-04-01",
            "shiftType": {
                "isNight": true
            }
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c6",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-01T05:30:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-02",
        "shift": {
            "isNight": false
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c7",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T00:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13e",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T04:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13f",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T12:40:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need the record should looks like bellow.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2023-04-01",
        "shift": {
            "date": "2023-04-01",
            "shiftType": {
                "isNight": true
            }
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c6",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-01T05:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6422d1b9994726677e9105c7",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T00:30:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-04-02",
        "shift": {
            "isNight": false
        },
        "attendances": [
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13e",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T04:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6423286e2746f65c2480a13f",
                "employee": "622061b73b2eaac4b15d42e4",
                "dateTime": "2023-04-02T12:40:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is is possible with mongodb with some quarry?
Please help me. Thanks in advance.